# How do I remove default white fill in Jasper report when export to Excel?

Tags: jasper-reports

When I export Jasper report to excel, it hides default excel boarders and fills the report lay out with white color. I tried selecting "Transparent" option in both "Style" properties and "Label" properties, still didn't work. I use JasperSoft studio. iReport Designer doesn't work in machine due to company policy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jaspersoft Studio you can go to Preferences/Jaspersoft Studio/Exporters/Excel Exporter and uncheck White Page Background.

Outside Jaspersoft Studio you would have to set the [net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background) property to false.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did first step just now. How do I do second step, "Outside Jaspersoft Studio you would have to set the net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background property to false."?  Sorry, I'm new to this stuff. Please help me in in making this change.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="mySheet" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="942" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="15" resourceBundle="mySheet">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.415765000000006"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
...
```

Comment: Could you please help me with my question? I have used property that you provide and the white fill was removed but looks like frame's background color(default is white) is still being printed.